# Another word for "dominate"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I’m trying to find a better word for “dominate” in the following sentences. It feels to me that “dominate” has more of a “subdue” meaning rather than “having deep knowledge about something”, which is the case. Can someone suggest another word for that?

- The company **dominates** these practices and implements agile solutions
- The company **dominates** the challenge of working with multiple technologies within the same client.
- The company **dominates** the use of cognitive rule engines

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to say, so we can't tell you how to say it. None of your example sentences makes sense to me.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Nor to me.

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use *dominates* because you think it has a negative connotation, you could consider **lead** and its variations:

> The company is a **leader** in the practice and implementation of agile solutions.
>   The company is **leading** in the challenge of working with multiple technologies within the same client.
>   The company **leads** in the use of cognitive rule engines.

Answer (score 1):

Use **distinguishes itself** instead. For example - You could say that the company **has distinguished itself** in these fields of endeavor.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/distinguish

Answer (score 0):

Try **replacing** it with these [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dominate); *command, control, dictate, influence, lead, manage, monopolize, overshadow, prevail, or run*.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of wonder if you are translating the German word *beherrschen* which can mean both to dominate and to master a skill.

You could use **masters** for all your sentences, but there are other words too.

> The company [masters](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/master?s=t)
>   these practices and implements agile solutions
>
> master
>  to make oneself master of; become an adept in: to master a
>      language.

You can also use adept.

> The company are [adept](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/adept?s=t) at using cognitive engines.

adjective

```
very skilled; proficient; expert: an adept juggler.
```

You could 'master a challenge' too, but I prefer 'meet the challenge'.

> The company meet the challenge of working with multiple technologies
>   within the same client.